# why does com.apple.screensaver gets empty in MAC

Tags: macos, screensaver

From command line i am trying to read **com.apple.screensaver** plist and i found it as

```
macUUID=`ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | grep -i "UUID" | cut -c27-62`  
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print"   /Users/$curUser/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.screensaver.$macUUID.plist
```

My output is

Dict {

}

What may be the reason for this file to be empty, where else can we see screen saver settings value